# Is there any way to catch whole screen re-paint event? (windows, c#)

Tags: c#, windows, onpaint

Is there any way to catch whole screen re-paint event? (windows, c#)

I want to do CopyFromScreen only after screen was updated, not by timer.

Comment: You could take advantage of a bug in CopyFromScreen, it doesn't capture layered windows.  Set the form's Opacity property to 99, you won't have to hide it before making the capture.

Comment: What do you mean by "whole screen re-paint event"?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a whole screen paint. The system optimises and only updates invalid regions. I don't know what you are trying to achieve (you didn't say) but it sounds like a remote desktop type application. They typically use mirror drivers.

Comment: Yes, it will be an desktop application. Right now Im working on optimization. Maby you can give me direction to mirror drivers in c# ?

Comment: I don't think you can write a mirror driver in C#.

Answer (score 0):

> There is no such thing as a whole screen paint

- that is true, but the screen can't update faster than its refresh rate (60-80 fraps per second). You need to set a timer with that interval and to make screenshots in its Tick event.

Comment: presumably the question is posed so as to avoid polling